# How to pass Markdown file as this.props in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a site in React using Redux, and my goal is to have a /pages folder full of markdown files that'll represent a pages content.

I have a React Container (smart) and a React Component (dumb) that'll be used to render the content.  My thinking is that I'll import the markdown files to the parent container and pass them down to the child component to render them in the browser. I know I'll need to use something like markdown-it to convert the MD to HTML and maybe I'll need to use that in the child component.

My questions are:

1) How do I pass in markdown files from parent to child using this.props?
2) Am I on the right track? Is this the right way to go about it?

Here are my components:

**Page Parent Container**

```
import React from 'react'
import SamplePage from './../components/SamplePage'

export default class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <SamplePage />
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

**SamplePage Child Component**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default class SamplePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="page-container">
        <Link to="/" className="previous-link">Go Back Home</Link>

        // I want to render the MD here using {this.props.markdown}

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: In terms of rendering the markdown, there are many solutions already.  For example: https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown

Comment: Right, there are a lot of solutions to render the markdown. My issue is that I don't fully understand how to retrieve the markdown from my /page folder and pass it in as a property to then use something like markdown-it to render it in the component.

Comment: You can make HTTP request to fetch file contents. e.g. https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1) I recommend using a [Markdown to JSX parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx) to keep your templating safe (otherwise you'd likely have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`)

2) I'd run this parser during build time, so everything is already ready to go. If you're using webpack or browserify, you can add a custom loader/transformer function to look for `*.md` files being required and run it through the parser.

3) The parsed markdown is then simple JSX and can be required & dropped into your existing component as you've done above.

Comment: I see. I'm using gulp, so first I'd need to write a gulp task that takes all the markdown files in the page folder, convert them to jsx. Then, I can import those jsx files to be passed in as props from the parent to child component.

Comment: Gulp without a bundler? Then you'd need to create an interim directory and store the parsed files there and require them from that location. If you're using a bundler, it's a lot simpler to do this kind of thing.